# How the frame size getting below 64 bytes

Tags: ethernet, wireshark, tcpdump, ieee-802.3x

I did packet capture on my system, where i did packet capture on wireless adapter. i seen some frame size below than 64 bytes like 54 bytes and other frame size as well. I seen some document frame size should be minimum of 64 bytes for etherent.

Then how am seeing 54 bytes of frame size on on my wireless adapter. Is that because of wireless adapter?

Comment: a) wireless != ethernet, and b) you may not be seeing the full RF frame

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, capturing traffic on WLAN interfaces is tricky. I assume you're doing this with wireshark, so take a look here:

http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q7.10

Next, 802.11 header is a little bit different than 802.3, take a look at standard:

http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2007.pdf